# How to fix this error? java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: java, assertion

```
package test;

import models.ContactManager;
import models.Contact;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.text.ParseException;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ContactManagerTest {
    ContactManager contactManager;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws ParseException {
        contactManager = new ContactManager();
        contactManager.addContact(new Contact("Rita", "5556036071", "6700 Lincoln Ave", "Thumbtack", "07/15/2023" ));
        contactManager.addContact(new Contact("Alex", "3236063206", "6700 Lincoln Ave", "Thumbtack", "09/15/2023" ));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void contactAdded() throws ParseException {
       assertTrue(contactManager.contains(new Contact("Rita", "5556036071", "6700 Lincoln Ave", "Thumbtack", "07/15/2023")));
    }
    
}
```

Trying to do JUnit test and get the error:
java.lang.AssertionError
at test.ContactManagerTest.contactAdded(ContactManagerTest)

test contactAdded()

Comment: Does `Contact` override methods `equals()` and `hashCode()`? If so: please [edit] the post and show the code. If not: override them accordingly.

Comment: Edit question to add definitions of `ContactManager` and `Contact`. If i had to make random guess, you did not override `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contactManager.contains()` uses `equals()` to match the objects. You should define your custom `Contact.equals()` method to make this test pass.

In your current implementation the default `Object.equals()` is used. It match not the objects' content, but objects' references.